# String date to Date returns wrong time

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, locale

I have the following `dateFormatter`:

```
var date = Date()
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"UTC+01:00")
dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone as TimeZone!

let sweDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

And when I print out I get these values:

```
1: print(date) // 2016-11-01 10:16:19 +0000
2: print("\(dateFormatter.string(from: date))") // 2016-11-01 11:16:35
3: print(dateFormatter.date(from: sweDate)!) // 2016-11-01 10:16:41 +0000
```

The **second value** is the right one in string format, but when I convert it to `Date()` I get the wrong time, **third print**. Why does this happen and how do I solve it? It´s Swedish time zone.

Comment: Ok, so it does not do anything with the `dateFormatter.date(from: sweDate)!)` then? How can I get the second value to `Date`?

Comment: `Date` doesn't store the time zone so it always prints the UTC time no matter what the time zone you used upon formatting.

Comment: @ozgur, yes I got it but how can I get the second value to `Date` instead of `String`?

Comment: Basically, you can't. The time in `Date` type must always represent your time in UTC format. You can only use a time zone to convert that to a string in order to just display. Thus, you have two options here: First, you can implement a thin wrapper over `Date` class so you can store the time zone there. By this way, you can have a property named `localizedDate` which basically adds the time zone difference to the actual `Date` in UTC time. Second, there is an awesome 3rd party library named [`SwiftDate`](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) which exactly does this for you.

Comment: Could you give an example of the first option as an answer?

Comment: In the library I recommended, There is a struct named [`DateInRegion`](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Sources/SwiftDate/DateInRegion.swift). You might want to look at the implementation of that to get a better insight about how it can be done.

Comment: Seriously, why you all first create `NSTimeZone` object and then convert it to `TimeZone`? `TimeZone` has own constructors, why not just use them? It drives me crazy already.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Your printed dates have all different *seconds:* 19 vs 35 vs 41. Are those values really from the same run?

Comment: @MartinR, yes different runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Because String 'sweDate' does't incloud info of time zone,so you get the time for zero zone.